# Creating a function to programmatically create UILabels from a String Array in Swift4

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I am able to programmatically create a `UILabel`, but when I create a function do I have to put it in the `viewDidLoad()` method? I need to append the label to the view by using `self.view.addSubview(label)` but it is throwing an error, and my build then fails when it is outside of the `viewDidLoad()`.

Whenever I try to create the function outside the `viewDidLoad` method it states "use of unresolved identifier self". Is there anyway around this?

Also, when I do put the function within the `viewDidLoad` everything works fine, and the labels are created, but they are created on top of each other. I want the labels to be beside each other if possible?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    func createALabel(inputtedString: String) -> Void {
        let string = inputtedString
        let test = string.components(separatedBy: " ")

        for element in test {
            let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 35))
            label.center = CGPoint(x: 160, y: 285)
            label.textAlignment = .center
            label.textColor = UIColor.blue
            label.text = element
            label.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
            label.layer.borderWidth = 3.0
            self.view.addSubview(label)
        }
    }
}
```

[Even with the position change my labels are still stacking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvPez.png)

Comment: Use a `UIStackView` and add the labels to the stack view.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The labels will overlap if you give them all the same frame.

Comment: @Jazzin The error is located in a different file: `label.swift`

Comment: The goal is to have some text, and for each word have a label associated with it. The labels can not be on top of each other though, they have to be beside.

Comment: @Jazzin If you dont want the labels not to be on top of each other, change label's x or y. Check Bhavisha Khatri's answer

Comment: @Jazzin What do you have in Label.swift file? Update its code here

Comment: My fault I had this function in my label.swift file, and that was what was throwing the error, but my labels are still overlapping now even with the position change.

Comment: @Jazzin Did you delete label.center = CGPoint(x: 160, y: 285)

Comment: @RajeshKumarR deleting the label.center was perfect, so now if the sentence is too long it goes out of the screen. Would you say place the labels inside a UITextView, or ScrollView?

Comment: @Jazzin Using collection view is the best option. It makes your job easier. Check this https://github.com/riteshhgupta/TagCellLayout

Comment: @RajeshKumarR do you know why when in the stackview there labels are not wrapping on the screen?

Comment: @Jazzin Stackview is one directional. When you append a label to a horizontal stackview it doesn't align in next line.

Comment: @Jazzin Check updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a collection view is the best option. It makes your job easier. Try this

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    var wordsArr = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.register(WordCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "WordCell")
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-(5)-[collectionView]-(5)-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["collectionView":collectionView]))
        view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-(5)-[collectionView]-(5)-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["collectionView":collectionView]))

        createALabel(inputtedString: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam")
    }
    func createALabel(inputtedString: String) -> Void {
        wordsArr = inputtedString.components(separatedBy: " ")
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return wordsArr.count
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "WordCell", for: indexPath) as? WordCell ?? WordCell()
        cell.label.text = wordsArr[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let width = (wordsArr[indexPath.row] as NSString).boundingRect(with: CGSize.zero, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16.0)], context: nil).size.width
        let size = CGSize(width: width + 10
            , height: 35)
        return size
    }

}
class WordCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    let label = UILabel()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {

        backgroundColor = .white

        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16.0)
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.textColor = UIColor.blue
        label.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        label.layer.borderWidth = 3.0
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(label)

        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[label(35)]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["label":label]))
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[label]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["label":label]))
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to add one Integer variable to set x position. Here I have set xPos variable according to set x position

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        }

        func createALabel(inputtedString: String) -> Void {
            let string = inputtedString
            let test = string.components(separatedBy: " ")

             let xPos = 0
            for element in test {
                let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: xPos, y: 0, width: 60, height: 35))
               // label.center = CGPoint(x: 160, y: 285)
                label.textAlignment = .center
                xPos = xPos + 60 + 10   // Update xPos width 60 & 10 is gap between two label
                label.textColor = UIColor.blue
                label.text = element
                label.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
                label.layer.borderWidth = 3.0
                self.view.addSubview(label)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: When you use self outside of viewdidLoad() did it not throw an error for you?

Comment: @Jazzin It will throw an error only if you have createALabel method outside the ViewController class

Comment: @RajeshKumarR my function is within the viewcontroller class and I am still getting the error

Comment: @Jazzin Can you update the question with a screenshot

Comment: @Jazzin You have the error in label.swift not in ViewController.swift

Comment: Delete label.center = CGPoint(x: 160, y: 285)

Answer (score 1):

To manage such geometry `UIStackView` could be useful.
Also you do not need to call this method in viewDidLoad, loadView lifecycle method is more proper for this, when you want to initialize and manage your views 
programatically.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private let vstackView = UIStackView()
    private let horizontal_spacing = 20.0
    private let spaceConstantForLetter = 10.0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        vstackView.axis = .vertical
        vstackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        vstackView.alignment = .center
        vstackView.spacing = 10

        self.view.addSubview(vstackView)
        vstackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        vstackView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true


        createALabel(inputtedString: "this is a long test string that exceeds screen width")//
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    }


    func createALabel(inputtedString: String) -> Void {
        let string = inputtedString
        let test = string.components(separatedBy: " ")


        var horizontalStackList = [UILabel] ()

        for (index, element) in test.enumerated() {
            let label = UILabel()
            label.textAlignment = .center
            label.textColor = UIColor.blue
            label.text = element
            label.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
            label.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
            horizontalStackList.append(label)

            let totalLetterNumber = horizontalStackList.map { $0.text!.count }.reduce(0, +)

            let contentWidth = Double(totalLetterNumber) * spaceConstantForLetter //constant for a letter that takes how much space from screen
            let spacingWidth = Double(horizontalStackList.count - 1) * horizontal_spacing
            /*add left and right margins if exist*/
            if((CGFloat(spacingWidth + contentWidth) > UIScreen.main.bounds.width)  || index == test.count - 1) {
                let exceedingLabel = horizontalStackList.popLast()
                let hstackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: horizontalStackList)
                hstackView.axis = .horizontal
                hstackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                hstackView.spacing = CGFloat(horizontal_spacing)
                hstackView.alignment = .center
                vstackView.addArrangedSubview(hstackView)
                horizontalStackList.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
                horizontalStackList.append(exceedingLabel!)
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Edit: Word wrapping added as Jazzin want

[image: output of the code above]

Comment: When the sentence is long the words go off of the screen, they do not word wrap. I need word wrapping.